# Code is still looping after break

Tags: c#, foreach, process

I have 3 instances of the same app running.  If I have my program mark one to be killed, it works fine, and 2 remain running.  When I mark another to be killed, then it kills the remaining 2, instead of just one more.  If I put a messagebox before the "break;", it works correctly, only killing one more and leaving one running.  But without the messagebox, when I try to kill the second instance, it always kills both that one and the third instance.  Any idea why a messagebox there would make it work correctly?  I'm assuming some type of timing issue, but I can't figure out why, since there's a "break;".

```
foreach (WatcherScraperModel scraper in this.Scrapers.Except(scheduled.Where(x => x.Active)))
{
    totalinstances = 0;
    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        try
        {
            if (process.MainModule.FileName == scraper.FileName)
            {
                // get instances already running
                totalinstances++;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // certain core processes cannot be accessed, don't worry about it
        }
    }
    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        try
        {
            // only kill an instance if there's too many running
            if (process.MainModule.FileName == scraper.FileName && totalinstances > scheduled.Count(x => x.Active && x.FileName == scraper.FileName))
            {
                logger.DebugFormat("Killed {0} because it was not scheduled to be running", scraper.FileName);
                process.Kill();
                scraper.RestartRemaining = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // certain core processes cannot be accessed, don't worry about it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `totalinstances--` statement somewhere next to `process.Kill()` ?

Comment: `Process.Kill` does not block while the process is killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [`Process.Kill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited.

If you add a `process.WaitForExit();` after `process.Kill();` then the next time you call `Process.GetProcesses()` that process should not longer be there allowing your count to be correct.  This also explains why adding a message box fixes the problem as that will give the process time to stop before you continue with the outer `foreach` loop.

Comment: DOH!  I knew it had to be something silly.  I didn't even notice that in the documentation.  Thanks.